# Download multiple files with Async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, download

I have this code that works fine for one file download.

How can I add multiple files to download for this code?

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     WebClient client = new WebClient();
     client.DownloadProgressChanged += Client_DownloadProgressChanged;
     client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
     client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip"), @"c:\folder\10MB.zip");
 }

 private void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("completed");
 }

 private void Client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     progressBar1.Maximum = (int)e.TotalBytesToReceive / 100;
     progressBar1.Value = (int)e.BytesReceived / 100;
 }
```

Comment: Call `DownloadFileAsync()` multiple times. If your question is then _"But how to update my progress bar"_, congratulations, you've asked for the answer to a problem that can't be solved. You don't know how large the files are going to be on beforehand, so you'll have to think of an alternative. For example if you want to download 10 files, let each file represent 10% on the progress bar. (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/06/47937.aspx)

Comment: @CodeCaster: well, you could send the request with HttpWebRequest  instead of WebClient.

This class is more complex and provide smore features. **if** the server provides content-length, you could have the total of bytes you'll need to download. You don't need to read the stream right away, you could read all the streams sequentially whenever you want.

Comment: @CodeCaster it's not impossible but not trivial and probably can't be done with WebClient. Using HttpClient, the OP can check the size of each file from the response headers before starting the download. This can set the maximum value. Progress events should update a single `received` counter. In fact, multiple download operations could post to the same `Progress<T>` object, ensuring only one update event is processed at a time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos HttpClient also utilizes this information, namely in the `DownloadProgressChanged` event that is shown (`e.TotalBytesToReceive`). However, you don't always know how large an HTTP response is going to be, for example when reading a chunked response. See [RFC 7230 Section 3.3.3. Message Body Length](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3).

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple progress bars and multiple web clients. Each `WebClient` should use appropriate progress bar.